# Load PNG from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to load a png file depending on a message type form code behind, but without success. In XAML it works if I define the image source as follows:

```
<Image Name="MessageTypeImage" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="../Images/error_96px.png" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

In code behind I tried the following:

```
        MessageTypeImage = new Image();
        BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
        bi3.BeginInit();
        bi3.UriSource = new Uri($@"..\Images\stop_sign_96px.png", UriKind.Relative);
        bi3.EndInit();
        MessageTypeImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        MessageTypeImage.Source = bi3;
```

This seems not to work, the space is always blank but no error message. How do I need to compose the Uri correctly?

The image below shows the folder structure of the relevant project inside my solution in VS 2015.

[image]

Comment: Is your image copied to the output directory along with the binary (.exe)? Check the Build Action in the file properties. (But if it works from XAML, then please disregard my comment)

Comment: See the answer to the duplicate question. Then load your images by Resource File Pack URIs, e.g. `var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/stop_sign_96px.png"));`

Comment: Does not work. I do not have a resource file (yet). I simply want to load it from that Image directory as it works everywhere in XAML when I load it statically. And what do the three commas mean? (...application:,,,/...)

Comment: If these images are part of your Visual Studio project, their Build Action should be set to Resource and you should load them from Resource File Pack URIs. Otherwise you should set the Build Action to Content, and select that they are copied to the Output Directory, e.g. `bin/Debug/Images/stop_sign_96px.png`, from where you would load them by relative file URIs.

Comment: ok reading on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx